# Compression in Kotlin using zelory 3.0.1

Tags: list, kotlin, compression, uri, multipartform-data

I am trying to compress a list of Images in Kotlin using zelory Compressor before uploading with multipartform data.

```
fun uploadImages()
{

    progressUpdate.postValue(ProgressUpdate._WORKING)
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val params = LinkedHashMap<String, RequestBody>()
        repo.listUri.forEachIndexed {index,file->
            try {
                val compressedImageFile = Compressor.compress(context, File(file.path)) {
                    quality(50)
                 
                }
                params["myFiles$index\"; filename= \" + $index.jpeg"] =  InputStreamRequestBody(context, Uri.fromFile(compressedImageFile))
            }catch (e: Exception) {
                print("Error!")
            }
        }
        val response = repo.apiInterface?.uploadUri(previousRecNoForPod,"pod", "android", params)
        response?.enqueue(fileUploadResponse)
    }

}
```

I am having some issues with the file / path stuff. I believe the error is either
`File(file.path)` or `Uri.fromFile(compressedImageFile))`
Does anyone have any suggestions as to why I am having this issue?

Comment: What is the error? What's in the stacktrace?

Comment: @aSemy The error shows "The source file does not exist" therefore it leads me to believe the way I am trying to read in the file back to the Uri is incorrect, but I can't figure out what needs changed

Comment: same here did you find any solution for this ?